# How to allign textview and edittext parallel?

Tags: android

[image: How to Design a form like this image]

Am new for android development i need to make form design like in this image how can i achieve this

Comment: Have you started yet? If yes, share your code.

Comment: noo am confused how to start with how to design it

Comment: Use android Table layout : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/grid.html

Comment: First thing to do is actually attempt it. If you are confused about where to start, stack overflow is not the place to ask for help. If you have a **specific* problem, we can happily attempt to help. I would recommend reading the documentation relating to layout design

Answer (score 2):

Make a LinearLayout as below and include Child Views inside that as below:-

```
    <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#492bdeba"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtAmountPending"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <EditText                  
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: nested weights are bad for performance

Comment: these are not nested weights . If LinearLayout also have weight, then only it is considered as nested weights.

Comment: For your View there is no need to implement nested weights.

Comment: these are not nested weights @MedlinMoni. Have you tried this code. You can change weights for increase or decrease length of views.

Comment: how to display only cursor in editext

Comment: i will be visible to you automatically

Comment: i dont need the base of the editext need only cursor

Comment: use background @null it removes background but not cursor